# The appearance of elements in a random place expands the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a function that craeates divs with a circle.

Now they are all created and appear at the beginning of the page and go further in order.

Next, I need each circle to appear in a random place. I did this but there is only one problem.

When the circle appears on the edge of the page, it expands and scrolling appears

How can I limit this so that the circles don't go off the edge of the page?

```js
function createDiv(id, color) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  var currentTop = 0;
  var documentHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var documentWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  div.setAttribute('class', id);
  if (color === undefined) {
    let colors = ['#35def2', '#35f242', '#b2f235', '#f2ad35', '#f24735', '#3554f2', '#8535f2', '#eb35f2', '#f2359b', '#f23547'];
    div.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }
  else {
   div.style.backgroundColor = color; 
  }
  div.classList.add("circle");
  div.classList.add("animation");
  
  currentTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * documentHeight) + 1;
   currentLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * documentWidth) + 1;
   
   div.style.top = currentTop + "px";
   div.style.left = currentLeft + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
    
let i = 0;

const oneSecond = 1000;

setInterval(() => {
  i += 1;
  createDiv(`circle${i}`)
}, oneSecond);
```

```css
.circle {
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it comes from 2 things :

- The height and width of the circle are not compensated when you get the random positions
- The 20px margin should be compensated too

See here my version, if you have some questions I'll try to be more clear :)

```js
var widthHeight = 40; // <-- circle width
var margin = 20; // <-- margin - is it necessary ?
var delta = widthHeight + margin;

function createDiv(id, color) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  var currentTop = 0;
  var documentHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var documentWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  div.setAttribute('class', id);
  if (color === undefined) {
    let colors = ['#35def2', '#35f242', '#b2f235', '#f2ad35', '#f24735', '#3554f2', '#8535f2', '#eb35f2', '#f2359b', '#f23547'];
    div.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }
  else {
   div.style.backgroundColor = color; 
  }
  div.classList.add("circle");
  div.classList.add("animation");
  
  // Get the random positions minus the delta
  currentTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * documentHeight) - delta;
  currentLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * documentWidth) - delta;
  
  // Keep the positions between -20px and the current positions
  var limitedTop = Math.max(margin * -1, currentTop);
  var limitedLeft = Math.max(margin * -1, currentLeft);

  div.style.top = limitedTop + "px";
  div.style.left = limitedLeft + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
    
let i = 0;

const oneSecond = 1000;

setInterval(() => {
  i += 1;
  createDiv(`circle${i}`)
}, oneSecond);
```

```css
.circle {
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, that's what I need)